# Firebase DB security rules for Creating document

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have an app that uses Firebase realtime DB. 
The app allows **Users** to work with **Projects**. Each User have access to his projects and projects that are shared with him by other users. User can create new projects and share his projects with other users.

The app is just an HTML page hosted on static html server.

I figured the data structure and security rules for editing existing projects. Here is my data structure:

```
{
  users:
  {
     $userId:{
       ///private user data
     }
  },
  project:
  {
     $projectId:{
        data:{...},
        permissions:{
           $userId:"owner"|"read"|"write"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

And here is my security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "project":{
        "$projectId":
        {
          ".write":"root.child('project/'+$projectId+'/permissions/'+auth.uid).val()==='owner'",
          ".read":"root.child('project/'+$projectId+'/permissions/'+auth.uid).val()!==null",
          "data":{
            ".write":"root.child('project/'+$projectId+'/permissions/'+auth.uid).val()==='write'"
          }
        }
    },
  }
}
```

This allows user to read Project only if he is mentioned in project's permissions, write project's root if he is mentioned as Owner, and write project's data if he has write permission.

**PROBLEM:**

I am stuck with CREATING NEW PROJECT. What security rules should I write to allow any authenticated user to create new project? Create/Write a new node in Project/{newprojectId}/... if it does not exist. As I mentioned I only have a static HTML page and no backend logic, and I prefer to keep it like that, in the worst case I would consider Firebase functions.

Comment: To allow an authenticated user to write a new node: `".write": "auth != null && !data.exists() && newData.exist()"`. If that doesn't help you solve the problem, please share the minimum code that is giving problems.